# Why CGLayers are not blending?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, drawrect, cgcontext, cglayer

Why obj2 not blend with obj1 but without use CGLayer it works fine,same problem with CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint,Does CGLayer not support CGContextSetBlendMode??

```
    //Layer
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGLayerRef objectLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext (context, rect.size, NULL);
    CGContextRef objectContext = CGLayerGetContext (objectLayer);
    //obj1
    CGContextDrawImage(objectContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height), [[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"] CGImage]);
    //obj2
    CGContextSetBlendMode(objectContext, kCGBlendModeSoftLight);
    CGContextSetAlpha(objectContext, 0.5f);
    CGContextDrawImage(objectContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height), [[UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay1.png"] CGImage]);
    CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, rect, objectLayer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only setting the blend mode *within* the layer's context, so the image is rendered on top of a transparent background with the soft light blend mode (which I think has the same effect as rendering it with the normal blend mode).

The blend mode of `context` is still set to normal, so the layer (which is already rendered) will be rendered with that mode. Blend modes do not cross context boundaries.